# How to design linear regression when BOTH independent and dependent variable are Poisson?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I have found a lot of discussions about GLM that are suitable for *Poisson regression*, or even *Poisson PCA*

However, I believe most of these cases don't take into account the case that the independent variables are also Poisson. I am wondering if there is a name for such problems so that I can google. Can someone provide a quick introduction here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Extremely few regression techniques make distributional assumptions about the independent variables, because most of them (apart from some classical multivariate Normal situations) concern the responses *conditional* on the explanatory variables.  You don't need an introduction to anything and I doubt there's even a name for this situation.  Poisson PCA could be different, but it's not clear what that would even be.  Do you have an application in mind?

Answer (score 1):

While the comment that few assumptions are usually made about independent variables (covariates), it can help to think about putting them on a sensible scale and/or to consider measurement uncertainty.

E.g. when analyzing some event count during a year, one obvious predictor could be the event count in the previous year. If you use Poisson (or negative binomial) regression, you tend to use a log-link, which means if you think the two might be proportional to each other, then using the log of the events in the previous year would be a logical way of transforming the covariate (possibly $\log(x+0.5)$ or so, to deal with the possibility of zeros).

What we ignore in the example above, is the uncertainty about the event rate that we estimate as a covariate. Ways of dealing with that for continuous data would be a measurement error model. Alternatively, for Poisson (or NegBin) regression, you could do a hierarchical model (aka random effects model) for both time periods. That can be a better approach, but has its limitation in some situations (e.g. you might have to model the whole selection process, if only those units with >X events get looked at or other situations like that).